# Macro's in PROC DB2EXT Queries?

Tags: sql, sas, db2, sas-macro

Is it possible to put Macro variables in a PROC DB2EXT query?

This works:

```
WHERE SDD BETWEEN '01.05.2018' AND '30.05.2018'
```

But all my attempts of inserting a Macro variable all result in errors

> Declaration of Macro

```
/* Statement in SAS, declaring the Macro, and transfering in to the remote session */
%let month =    05;
%SYSLPUT MONTH  =   &month;
%PUT &MONTH;
```

> DB2EXT SQL

```
/* Error(-180): DSN00180E THE DATE, TIME, OR TIMESTAMP VALUE 01."&month.".2018 IS INVALID  */
WHERE SDD BETWEEN '01."&month.".2018' AND '30.05.2018'

/* Error(-206): DSN00206E 01.MAY.2018 IS NOT VALID IN THE CONTEXT WHERE IT IS USED */
WHERE SDD BETWEEN "01.&month..2018" AND '30.05.2018'

/* Futile attemps */
WHERE SDD BETWEEN '01&month2018' AND '30.05.2018'
WHERE SDD BETWEEN '01month2018' AND '30.05.2018'
```

Comment: Try using ISO-format literal values in the DB2EXT query, i.e. so the literal ends up looking like 'YYYY-MM-DD'  (for a date literal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following construct When generating single quoted literals that need to contain an evaluated macro variable:

```
%str(%')macro-evaluation%str(%')
```

*Ignore the slightly weird stack overflow (SO) colorizing of the above code. The SO renderer can't decipher the single quote as part of %str() closure*

So your case could be

```
%str(%`)01&month.2018%str(%')
```